# Is this mysqli wrapper secure against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

Here is how a wrapper looks like:

```
<?php
    
    Class mysqliwrapper{
        protected $_mysqli;
        protected $_debug;
     
        public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database, $debug) {
            $this->_mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
            $this->_debug = (bool) $debug;
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                if ($this->_debug) {
                    echo mysqli_connect_error();
                    debug_print_backtrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
     
        public function q($query) {
            if ($query = $this->_mysqli->prepare($query)) {
                if (func_num_args() > 1) {
                    $x = func_get_args();
                    $args = array_merge(array(func_get_arg(1)),
                        array_slice($x, 2));
                    $args_ref = array();
                    foreach($args as $k => &$arg) {
                        $args_ref[$k] = &$arg; 
                    }
                    call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), $args_ref);
                }
                $query->execute();
     
                if ($query->errno) {
                  if ($this->_debug) {
                    echo mysqli_error($this->_mysqli);
                    debug_print_backtrace();
                  }
                  return false;
                }
     
                if ($query->affected_rows > -1) {
                    return $query->affected_rows;
                }
                $params = array();
                $meta = $query->result_metadata();
                while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                    $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
                }
                call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $params);
     
                $result = array();
                while ($query->fetch()) {
                    $r = array();
                    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                        $r[$key] = $val;
                    }
                    $result[] = $r;
                }
                $query->close(); 
                return $result;
            } else {
                if ($this->_debug) {
                    echo $this->_mysqli->error;
                    debug_print_backtrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
     
        public function handle() {
            return $this->_mysqli;
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

This works fine:

```
$w = new mysqliwrapper("localhost","root","","testdb",1);

$r = $w->q("SELECT * FROM `testdb_news` WHERE `id`=? AND `lang`=?","is",16,'en');
```

However, this does not:

```
$r = $w->q("INSERT INTO `testdb_news` ('lang','title','content','date') VALUES (?,?,?,?)","ssss","en","NewTitle","NewContent",mktime());
```

Why? Should I be using ?-s only for SELECT statements? And go for insert like this?

```
$r = $w->q("INSERT INTO `testdb_news` (lang,title,content,date) VALUES ('en','newTitle','newContent','".mktime()."')");
```

Is this secure? Is this class actually secure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

safe against injections. see this question which has similar questions [Parameterized Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500070/parameterized-query)