# New line in MySQL update

Tags: php, mysql

I made a page where users are able to edit text that goes straight into my SQL database. The problem however is that SQL ignores new lines in the HTML textarea. For example, when I type:

- 1
- 2
- 3

It shows "123" when I run a SELECT query. How can I adjust the code so SQL does not ignore new lines in the textarea?

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']) 
    || $_SESSION['ingelogd'] !== true) {
    header('Location: /xxxx/xxxx/Login.php');
    exit;
}
?>


<CSS code removed>

       <?php
function sanitize($data) {
return stripslashes(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($data))));
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
if (!empty($_POST["inhoud"])) {

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Database error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sanitize_post = $_POST["inhoud"];
$sanitize_post = sanitize($sanitize_post);
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tekstpagina SET inhoud='$sanitize_post' WHERE naam='over'");

mysqli_close($con);
}
}



?>

<b>Update:</b>
<form action="" method="post"><br><textarea id="styled" name="inhoud"></textarea>
<br/><input type="submit" value="Bijwerken" name="Update">
   </form>

    </p>
```

Comment: I find your "sanitize" function to be terrifying.  See my post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7810880/362536

Comment: Stop. No. Don't. `mysqli` has a robust escaping system you are completely ignoring. Use `[bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)`. **DO NOT** do what you're doing here. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or there will be severe consequences.

Comment: It is "terrifying", Brad. I'm fixing the code after everything is working.

Comment: That sanitize function is... Like a cheddar cheese.  Use mysqli and parameterized queries. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500070/parameterized-query

Comment: Also, I believe it is also your sanitize function that is stripping the \n needed for line breaks. Otherwise use htmlentities()

Comment: HTML escaping should be done just before it's rendered to a page, never when stored in the database. You run the risk of double-escaping if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll remove the function and try your suggestions.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` adds slashes, you remove them. That seems kind of worse than just using one function.